# How to persist query variables across internal <nuxt-link/> components?

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt3, nuxt-link

I have a Nuxt3 app, and I am needing to persist any query variables across all internal instances of .

An example would be if a user were to arrive from a Google ad, several query variables would be appended to the URL. However once I start clicking around on internal buttons, those query variables are lost.

I was looking into global middleware that would look for `from.query`, and if that exists, set that to `to.query`, however it doesn't appear to run when clicking on any  (I only see console logs on page refresh).

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  console.log({ from });
  console.log({ to }); <-- these don't run across pages

  if (from.query) {
    to.query = from.query;
  }
});
```

I suppose one way would be to manually alter each and every nuxt-link within the application to look for query variables and append those to the href, however there are a ton of buttons and would require a lot of code duplication.

What's the best way to persist these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a global middleware where you use the suggested function for redirect that is `navigateTo()`.

Global middlewares are created using the suffix `global` in the file name in the `middleware` folder.

The code to redirect to any `NuxtLink` path if a query is present in the current page and a query is not declared by the link could be:

- middleware/persistQuery.global.js

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {

  if (Object.keys(from.query).length && !Object.keys(to.query).length) {

    return navigateTo({
      path: to.path,
      hash: to.hash,
      params: to.params,
      query: from.query,
      redirectCode: 302, // default
    });
  }
});
```

I created a simple project where you can verify that the `{ foo: 'bar' }` query (or any other query provided), is preserved while you navigate back and forth between the home, the contact page and the page with id param:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-rw7pv4?initialpath=?foo=bar

Documentation:

Middleware directory:

> There are three kinds of route middleware:
> 3. Global route middleware, which are placed in the middleware/ directory (with a .global suffix) and will be automatically run on every route change.

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware#format

navigateTo:

> navigateTo is a router helper function that allows programmatically navigating users through your Nuxt application.
> navigateTo is available on both server side and client side. It can be used within plugins, middleware or can be called directly to perform page navigation.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/navigate-to